# JMeter Latency (TTFB) accuracy

Tags: http, jmeter, performance-testing

While capturing latency for the HTTP GET requests, I observe that the latency in ms is relativey quite higher than what I see in wireshark capture for a single packet. For example, a GET of a 4KB text file, i could see JMeter reporting latency as 153 (I assume this to be in ms), but wireshark says it as 12ms.

Is there something I am missing here to understand?

I am using jmeter 2.12 for my performance testing and all the GET, PUT operations I am planning are on text, image and video files which could span from 4KB to 2GB.

Comment: jmeter is giving the time from request sent to response received, what does wireshark measure?

Comment: In wireshark I am measuring the time taken to send the request on the wire and receive the first byte of the response (I just collected this manually by looking into one request). i.e. first data packet arriving after 200 OK. I also had stats from the server under test, and latency measured there is difference of the time when the message arrived on the connection layer of the server to the time taken to send the first byte of the response from connection layer.

Comment: This time is very similar to what I saw on wireshark when collected from client. I have dedicated 10 gbps connection between the client (jmeter) and server and there should be no other network interference on the wire. Is that there is major overhead on framing the packet from jmeter and while receiving, decoding it and them measuring the latency?

Comment: jmeter is not including its overhead in the response time. overhead can affect how many requests you can send per second, but does not affect the reporting of response time. ie considering one thread only, total response times will not represent test duration

Comment: So, will I have some jmeter logging which tells when the timer started ticking for request sent and when it stopped.I would like to do this by sending a single GET requests on one thread group. I would like to see why such huge delta is seen. Is this possible?

Comment: Also, one more quick question. If Server challenges the request with 401, is latency measured in jmeter also includes the first GET for which 401 is received and a new GET with Auth header and first byte of response or does it only include the time taken to frame new GET post 401 with Auth header and first byte of the response?

Comment: in the View Results Tree listener, you can see the start and end times for the sample in the sampler result tab. If you run in non-gui mode, as you should for final metrics, the default is to save the timestamps in your output jtl file. You can look in there.

Comment: yes if you are redirected, the response time is for the entire transaction (from 1st request to last response). Perhaps that is where you are losing your times, you could try directing your test to the last page you are being redirected to.

Comment: Thanks Charlie for clarification. Unfortunately, I do not know the nonce provided by server so cannot pre-construct Auth headers in test plan before runs.